# bootable disk and application on one DVD?

Tags: boot, dvd, livedvd

I have a program I want to use that only runs on a Linux OS.  I'm in the process of creating an Ubuntu bootable DVD so my Windows 7 computer can run the program.  My question is can I also burn the program I want to run on the same DVD, or does the bootable DVD need to be dedicated strictly to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom live CD/DVD/USB `.iso` image (based on the official desktop CD ISO, or the official desktop DVD ISO, or any other similar ISO), that includes the program you want to run.

- [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)